# Rearrange dataframe to a table, the opposite of "melt"

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have huge dataframe like this:

```
SN = c(1:100, 1:100, 1:100, 1:100)  
class = c(rep("A1", 100), rep("B2", 100), rep("C3", 100), rep("D4", 100)) # total 6000 levels 
myvar = rnorm(400)
mydf = data.frame(SN, class, myvar)
```

I want to "unmelt" to a table with each level as single column and myvar in filled:

```
SN          A1            B2          C3         D4       .............and so on for all 6000
```

How can I achieve this, I know it is simple question, but I could not figure out.

Comment: In package `reshape2` the opposite of `melt` is `cast`

Comment: thanks for suggestions, require(reshape2); acast(mydf, myvar ~ class) produced awaful result

Comment: See answer below for correct syntax. It's really quite natural after you use it a couple times. Much better than built-in `reshape()`.

Comment: Think of your desired table output like a plot: We want `SN` varying in the vertical direction (like `y`), and `class` varying in the horizontal direction (like `x`). So instead of `y ~ x`, we have `SN ~ class`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9617424/210673 for a similar question with a list of ways to do this.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
> dcast(mydf, SN ~ class)

  SN         A1         B2          C3          D4
1  1  0.1461258  0.8325014  0.33562088 -0.07294576
2  2  0.5964182  0.4593710 -0.23652803 -1.52539568
3  3  2.0247742 -1.1235963  1.79875447 -1.87462227
4  4  0.8184004  1.3486721  0.76076486 -1.18311991
5  5 -0.6577212  0.3666741 -0.06057506  1.38825487
6  6  0.1590443  0.2043661  0.08161778  0.10421797
...
```

Comment: Note: this is from the `reshape2` library.

Comment: Also note that the "best practice" would be: dcast(mydf, SN ~ class, value.var="myvar")

Comment: Um, should this work? `iris_melt <- melt(iris); dcast(iris_melt, Species~variable)`? Because it doesn't. It gives counts (a species by measurement table).

Comment: @naught101: That happens when there's more than one row for a given combination.  If there's only one, it uses the value.

Answer (score 8):

```
molten = melt( mydf , id.vars = c( "SN" , "class" ) , measure.vars = "myvar" )
casted = dcast( molten , SN~class )
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with `split`:

```
mydfSplit <- split(mydf[,-2], mydf$class, drop=TRUE)
```

The result is a list which can be easily converted to a `data.frame` if the components have the same dimensions (which is true in this example):

```
mydf2 <- do.call(cbind, mydfSplit)
```

The problem with this solution is that the names of the final result need a cleaning. However, for a more general data, this can be useful if `SN` is different for each class.

Answer (score 1):

In base R you could do it like this...

```
# get it sorted so that all you need to do is make a matrix out of it
mydf <- mydf[order(mydf$class, mydf$SN),]
# save the unique values of SN
SNu <- unique(mydf$SN)
# combine a matrix with SN
mydfw <- data.frame(SNu, matrix(mydf$myvar, nrow = length(SNu)))
# name your columns    
colnames(mydfw) <- c('SN', levels(mydf$class))
```

Or, for a more concise expression using aggregate

```
aggregate(myvar~SN, mydf, 'c')
# column names don't come out great
colnames(mydfw) <- c('SN', levels(mydf$class))
```

Comment: That assumes that all combinations of levels are present, which, in general, is a dangerous assumption to make.

Comment: It works for the example. You just don't like the first one because it's very fast. :) But kidding aside, questioner, Hadley is correct, if you don't have a complete matrix then the this won't work correctly.  You could just merge with a complete factorial design using expand.grid for the factors of interest.